# how to create a JDialog which can only floating within its parent frame

Tags: java

I want to create a `JDialog` which can only float within its parent Frame. That is it cannot be dragged out from its parent frame. Any idea? mouse-motion listener?

thanks,

**EDIT:**

1. My applicaiton is based on frame not internal frame, so I cannot use `JInternalFrame`
2. I need a non-modal dialog so, I cannot use JOptionPane with internal feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you should have specified the "hidden" problem in the initial question.

I've have found a very tricky solution, I don't suggest to use it except from developing a better one, perhaps starting from this. 
Given an JInternalFrame, provide it with a componentMove listener to inhibit moving it in hidden positions.
As far as I've tested it, it has refresh problems (maybe they can be solved) and the stability in extreme case to assess too.
Provided "as is" for further improvement, not as a nice piece of software :-)

```
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

                Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

                MyInternalFrame mif = MyInternalFrame.this;
                JDesktopPane dp = mif.getDesktopPane();

                if (mif.getX() + mif.getWidth()> dp.getWidth()) {
                    mif.setLocation(mif.getDesktopPane().getWidth()-mif.getWidth(),mif.getY());
                }

                if (mif.getY() + mif.getHeight()> dp.getHeight()) {
                    mif.setLocation(mif.getX(), mif.getDesktopPane().getHeight()-mif.getHeight());
                }

                if (mif.getX()<0) {
                    mif.setLocation(0, mif.getY());
                }

                if (mif.getY()<0) {
                    mif.setLocation(mif.getX(), 0);
                }

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`JInternalFrame`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) instead. See [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for an example.

Comment: Yes, but the InternalFrame can be totally hidden on the edge of its parent frame. Any way to avoid this? I don't want the internal frame or floating dialog be partial or totallly hidden by its parent frame. that means the left side border of the internal frame or the dialog cannot go beyond the left side border of its parent frame.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA: See the methods including the string 'internal' in [JOptionPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

Comment: Please see the edit above. I cannot use JOptionPane because I need a non-modal dialog to display some data received.